# How to change Frame source in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, navigation, frame, silverlight-5.0

I have a xaml file defined like this:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
.....
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="800">

<sdk:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Source="/MainPageContent.xaml">

</sdk:Frame>
</UserControl>
```

Whole content of page is stored in MainPageContent. I've made another file, called for example PageTwoContent.xaml. How i can change source of Frame to new xaml file for example by button?

Answer (score 2):

The xaml page should have something along the lines of this

```
<Button>
 ...
 Click="ClickEvent"
</Button>
```

On the code-behind, you'd have something like the following:

```
private void ClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do any other event stuff here
    this.ContentFrame.Source = new Uri("/PageTwoContent.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
}
```

I've had some issues with this working, so sometimes you can also call Refresh() on your ContentPane afterwards to force it to refresh the content from the source for the frame.